# Python How to use the update id in an API call and iterate until all data is collected

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-requests

I am using the Anomali Threatstream API which returns at most 1000 rows at a time.  However I am trying to pull back all the information from my call.  The data comes back in json format which is easy to handle and converts to a pandas dataframe nicely. The documentation suggests using the update_id and iterate.

The API documentation states, "`Using “update_id” to Retrieve Large Intelligence Datasets For the Intelligence API, in cases where the total number of results is greater than 10,000, Anomali recommends using update_id to return the full dataset via iterativeAPI calls.Usingtheupdate_id method ensures large datasets are retrieved without impacting performance.`"

**This method involves appending the following to your API call**: `update_id__gt=0&order_by=update_id`

"`After the first call is made, locate the update_id of the last returned result. Use this value for the update_id__gt variable in your next API call. Repeat this process iteratively until no further results are returned.`"

My API call looks like the following:

```
response = requests.get("https://api.threatstream.com/api/v2/intelligence/?username=<username>&api_key=<api_key>&created_ts__gte=2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&created_ts__lte=2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z&tags.name=ingestedemails")
```

My current code looks like this:

```
import requests
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

#API call
response = requests.get("https://api.threatstream.com/api/v2/intelligence/?username=<username>&api_key=<api_key>&created_ts__gte=2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&created_ts__lte=2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z&tags.name=ingestedemails")

#Load data(json format) from API request
data = json.loads(response.text)
values = data['objects']

#Convert from json format to pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient='columns')
df = df[['created_ts','value','source']]
```

I would assume this would be a loop.  What would this looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that `requests.get` can [assemble the url](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) itself if you pass in the parameters as a `dict`

The method that gets the data can look somewhat like this:

```
def get_data(url, parameters):
    parameters = parameters.copy()
    parameters["update_id__gt"] = 0
    parameters["order_by"] = "update_id"
    while True:
        response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
        if not response.text: # or other sign there are no further results
            return

        data = json.loads(response.text)
        values = data["objects"]
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient="columns")

        yield df[["created_ts", "value", "source"]].copy()
        # copy() the relevant piece because else pandas might keep a reference to the whole dataframe

        parameters["update_id__gt"] = df["update_id"].iloc[-1]
```

Then this can be called like this, using `pandas.concat` to assemble the partial results:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "https://api.threatstream.com/api/v2/intelligence/"
    parameters = {
        "username": "<username>",
        "api_key": "<api_key>",
        "created_ts__gte": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "created_ts__lte": "2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z",
        "tags.name": "ingestedemails",
    }
    all_data = pd.concat(get_data(url, parameters))
```

This code is not tested, so might need some tweaking

Comment: Thank you @Maarten Fabré I know you are helping me blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json

#Variables that feed the API call
url = 'https://api.threatstream.com/api/v2/intelligence/?username='
username = '<username>'
api_key = '<api_key>'
start_date_time = '2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'
end_date_time = '2019-02-28T23:59:59.999Z'
source = '28'

start_num = str(0) #variable to set update_id__gt=0

apiCall = url+username+'&api_key='+api_key+'&created_ts__gte='+start_date_time+'&created_ts__lte='+end_date_time+'&trustedcircles='+source+'&update_id__gt='+start_num+'&order_by=update_id'
response = requests.get(apiCall) #Define response
data = json.loads(response.text) #Load the json data
values = data["objects"] #Convert to objects
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient="columns") #Create pandas dataframe from data objects

new_max_update_id = str(df['update_id'].iloc[-1] + 1) #Find the last update_id and add 1 for a starting place in next api call

#Run until the length of df2 is less than 1000
while True:
    try: 
        apiCall = url+username+'&api_key='+api_key+'&created_ts__gte='+start_date_time+'&created_ts__lte='+end_date_time+'&trustedcircles='+source+'&update_id__gt='+new_max_update_id+'&order_by=update_id'
        response = requests.get(apiCall)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
        values = data["objects"]
        df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient="columns") #Convert new data to dataframe
        df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True) #Add new data to df
        new_max_update_id = str(df2['update_id'].iloc[-1] + 1) #Update starting point for next api call
    except:
        if len(df2) < 1000: #If lenth is less than 1000 then stop looping
            break
```